# curl: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

Lately, on my Mac, I ran this command :

`curl https://randomuser.me/api/`

I keep getting

> curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Have you guys faced something like this before ?

It used to work. :( 
It used to return me a list of data.

```
{"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"mrs","first":"tamara","last":"beyer"},"location":{"street":"3250 jahnstraße","city":"torgau-oschatz","state":"sachsen","postcode":28295},"email":"tamara.beyer@example.com","login":{"username":"bigwolf528","password":"jennifer","salt":"dn4vwusR","md5":"47cbc9953f76fc8882e47e9d1e6b30ed","sha1":"965105a6c81d6bf4909688fdd9c580d02f6c4ef6","sha256":"f9c54871a37154996d02fd489ae635688ba7adfe5ef0914b925d1eaeb39b5adb"},"dob":"1947-11-20 00:29:05","registered":"2006-07-17 13:07:06","phone":"0738-5061390","cell":"0173-4406143","id":{"name":"","value":null},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/0.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/0.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/0.jpg"},"nat":"DE"}],"info":{"seed":"75362ef6e82d3778","results":1,"page":1,"version":"1.1"}}
```

Any suggestion on what I should look into ?

---

**Updated**

I've follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure) and tried. Here are my result :

```
└── curl -2 https://randomuser.me/api/
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to randomuser.me:443 


└── curl --sslv2 https://randomuser.me/api/
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to randomuser.me:443 


└── curl -3 https://randomuser.me/api/
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure


└── curl --sslv3 https://randomuser.me/api/
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure


└── curl -L https://randomuser.me/api/
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

---

**curl -V**

```
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8zd zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.20 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure

Comment: I've tried those suggestions already. Should I tried something elses ?

Comment: What is your version of curl and the configuration?. Please add the output of `curl -V` to your question. My guess is that it is compiled an old version of openssl (i.e. 0.9.8) which does support any of the ciphers the server requires. The server requires all ECDHE ciphers which are not supported by OpenSSL 0.9.8.

Comment: Try to upgrade curl

Comment: I've added it.. please have a look.